# How to configure select Field (wtforms)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm new to Python web development, so I need your help.
I have in forms.py

```
class AddForm(FlaskForm):
fio = StringField('ФИО', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=140)])
tovar = StringField('Товар', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=140)])
...
```

routes.py:

```
def add_client():
form = AddForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    ld = Lead(fio = form.fio.data, tovar = form.tovar.data, price = form.price.data, contact = form.contact.data, address = form.address.data, cost_price = form.cost_price.data, profit = form.price.data-form.cost_price.data, track = form.track.data, status = form.status.data, user_id = current_user.id)
    db.session.add(ld)
    db.session.commit()
    ...
```

And clients_manager.html:

```
        <div class="col">
            <label>Товар</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                    {% for lead in current_user.leads %}
                    <option>{{ lead.tovar }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
```

How can I configure all this so that I get data from SelectField into the database. Thank you!